# Expand image to full screen on touch in iOS

Tags: ios5, animation, uiimageview, uiimage

I want to accomplish this:

Load a UIViewController with a image in some part of it. The image should be a little smaller than the original and also cropped in top and botton and when touch on it to animate into full screen.

Something like JetSetter app does

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

Comment: I've tried setting the image as a button with an action to expand it. I'm not sure if I have to expand the image with an animation to be over the all other thing in the view.